# Поиск и суммирование всех значений на странице Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

На странице такой исходный код:

```
<li id="transaction-100" class="bankingTransaction " >
    <div class="extra">
                <span class="negativeAmount">-100</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alertText">
        <h3>Оплата </h3>
        
    </div>
</li>
<li id="transaction-101" class="bankingTransaction " >
    <div class="extra">
                <span class="negativeAmount">-200</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alertText">
        <h3>Оплата </h3>
        
    </div>
</li>
<li id="transaction-102" class="bankingTransaction " >
    <div class="extra">
                <span class="negativeAmount">-300</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alertText">
        <h3>Другое</h3>
        
    </div>
</li>
```

Как мне собрать только те значения (без знака минус), где в теге `<h3>` есть текст "Оплата" и просуммировать их?
Т.е. из этого когда мне нужно получить 100+200= 300

Пытался хотя бы просто все классы найти и просуммировать значения.

```
 balance = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('negativeAmount')
 print(sum(balance))
```

Как итог:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'WebElement'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы получаете элемент страницы через функцию find_element_by_class_name, она в свою очередь возвращает тоже элемент страницы.
Чтобы суммировать значения, в данном случае нужно получить текст элемента, и перевести его из str в int тип.

Решение для одного элемента:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class").text
amount = int(text)
```

Решение для нескольких элементов вариант 1:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class")
amount_list = [int(element.text) for element in elements]
```

Решение для нескольких элементов вариант 2:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class")
amount_list = []

for element in elements:
    element = int(element)
    amount_list.append(element)
```

Последние два решения идентичны, просто второе более явное чем первое.